# Existence of a global minimum

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $S = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}: x > 0, y >0, z > 0\}$ and consider $f(x, y, z) = xyz + \frac{1}{xyz}$. Why must $f$ attain a global minimum at some $p \in S$?

Comment: Thie function $f$ is of class $C^2$ in the region $S$. Necessary and sufficient conditions for a local minimum at some point $p$ is that the gradient of $f$ is zero at that point and the Hessian at that point is a positive-definite matrix. You have to solve the equation $\nabla f(x) = 0$ and verify that the Hessian is a positive-definite matrix at some of the points that solve that equation. A global minimum must be one of those local minimums. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$xyz + \frac{1}{xyz} \ge 2\sqrt{xyz \cdot \frac{1}{xyz}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(r)=r+\frac{1}{r}$ for $r>0$.  Then $g$ attains a global minimum at $r=1$,

since $r+\frac{1}{r}\ge 2$ for $r>0$ since $r^2-2r+1=(r-1)^2\ge0$.

Therefore $f$ attains a global minimum at any point $(x,y,z)$ with $xyz=1$ and
$x>0, y>0, z>0$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\left(\sqrt{xyz}-\sqrt\frac{1}{xyz}\right)^2\geq0$ for every $(x,y,z)\in{}S$ and from this, we get
$$xyz+\frac{1}{xyz}\geq{}2\sqrt{xyz}\sqrt\frac{1}{xyz}=2$$
So $f(x,y,z)\geq2$ for every $(x,y,z)\in{}S$. In addition, it is evident that $f(1,1,1)=2$.
So $f$ has a global minimum at $(1,1,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that for all $u\in\mathbb{R}^+$,
$$
u+\frac1u=\left(\sqrt{u}-\frac1{\sqrt{u}}\right)^2+2\ge2
$$